# Script to copy files to x locations of rules are met

Tags: macos, shell-script, automator

I would like to create an automator script that will ask me for a specified folder, and on selection I would like it to search for the following and do x tasks

- if files is .mkv and does not contain "sample" in the filename and is < 2GB copy to x location
- if files is .mkv and does not contain "sample" in the filename and is > 2GB copy to z location.
  For any files that do not meet these requirement the file should be deleted along with the parent folder that was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run a shell script like this in a code editor like [TextMate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate):

```
d=~/Folder
find "$d" -name '*.mkv' -a ! -name '*sample*' -a -size -2G -exec cp {} ~/x \;
find "$d" -name '*.mkv' -a ! -name '*sample*' -a -size +2G -exec cp {} ~/z \;
rm -r "$d"
```

- \; takes one argument at a time (\+ would take multiple arguments), but in this case copying files takes much longer than starting new cp processes
- 2G is 2 GiB (2*2^30 bytes)
- +2G and -2G are exclusive, but there probably won't be files that are exactly 2 Gib
- [{} doesn't have to be quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/quoting-curly-braces-in-the-shell)
- cp doesn't keep modification or creation times unless you add -p (or -a, which implies -p)
- You could also use [trash](http://hasseg.org/trash/) instead of rm -r

Comment: How can I intergrate this with a "Ask for Finder Items" action? So it passes the folder input to the script?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out